# How to block progression in asyncio

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

So I understand that using `async ... await` python can prevent blocking and accomplish xyz to follow. But what about the opposite, where I *want* python to block xyz until an process has completed?

For example, suppose I have three functions, A,B & C where A should not block B and vice versa. But C should be blocked by both A and B?

```
async def A():
   # some code


async def B():
   # some code

def C():
   # some code

async def handler():
   # A and B not to block each other
   await A() 
   await B()
   # Must complete before C
   C()
```

As I understand it, asyncio will implicitly infer that C should be blocked by A and B if C is defined in terms of them (or their outputs.)

But in the event that C is not defined in terms of A & B, how can it be ensured that C will only commence when A and B are complete?

Comment: As you wrote it, `A`, `B` and `C` are executed one after the other. To run `A` and `B` without blocking each other you must make them tasks and wait for them to be finished, then execute `C`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run A, B in parallel and if they both finish, call `C()`. You can create tasks from `A()`, `B()`, use `asyncio.gather()` to wait for them to finish and then call `C()`:

```py
import asyncio


async def A():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("A finished")


async def B():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("B finished")


def C():
    print("In C!")


async def handler():
    # A and B not to block each other
    tasks = {asyncio.create_task(A()), asyncio.create_task(B())}
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    # Must complete before C
    C()


asyncio.run(handler())
```

Prints (and finishes in 2 seconds):

```
A finished
B finished 
In C!
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought when reading your requirement was "is this not an async-anti pattern". However after my coffee kicked in I realised that you're looking for guaranteed processing order.

I suggest reading the standard python docs on [Synchronization Primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html). Take note of Barrier, however going through these should trigger your imagination in finding the best pattern that suites your specific requirements.

Alternatively, you can use a [graph](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html) to help synchronise what tasks can run concurrently and which should wait. [I have published](https://github.com/robertbetts/Symphonizer) some of my experimentation is this area and you're welcome to get ideas from that.

Comment: Thanks, learning more about this space is fun/intriguing!